# Interesting tea-time problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

Problem A: Please fill each blank with a number such that all the statements are true:

0 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
1 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
2 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
3 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
4 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
5 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
6 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
7 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
8 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)
9 appears in all these statements $____$ time(s)

Note: they are treated as numbers, not digits. e.g. 11 counts as occurrence of 11, but not two 1.

**EDIT**
How do number of solutions behave, with respect to number of statements there are? I need a sketch of the proof.

Comment: For problem B, won't the smallest number always be 0?  Also, does $11$ count as two appearances of $1$, or one appearance of $11$?

Comment: yes you are right, i will change to smallest positive number

Comment: @ErickWong, lets consider 11 as a number not as two digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note this does carry the assumption of counting the occurrence of the number at the start of the statement and not strictly in the boxes as there is a bit of interpretation there:

The first one has at least one solution. 1732111211 would be the values where there are 7 1s in the statements occurring in the all but 3 of the lines, those being the 2,3, and 7 lines.  2 appears 3 times as it is the number of 7s and 3s in the sequence.  3 appears twice as it is the number of 2s as well as its own line for its other appearance.

---

The first one would appear to be easily generalized as if one wanted to take away the line with 9s, then the number of 1s will drop to 6 and the 2 that was on the 7s will come down one row.  This could be repeated up to a few times I'd think.  0,1,5, and 6 would give 4 times that a 1 would appear so for at least 7 rows this can be done.  One could add lines for 10,11, and so on which would increase the number of 1s and then the 2 that is on the 7s would shift up.

Answer (score 3):

For the revised B there are exactly 3 solutions consisting of single digits: $173311121291$, $174121121291$, $191311111391$.  No single-digit solutions were found to the original B, and the solution to A is unique within this class.

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Hofstadter wrote about these problems years ago.  He suggested a useful approach is to fill in the blanks with something, then just count and refill, iterating to convergence.  On the first one, I got trapped in a loop between $1741111121$ and $1821211211$ and for the second a loop between $254311311150$ and $262323111160$ where the largest is taken from the current iteration instead of the last.

Comment: For the first one $1732111211$ works.

Comment: Did he talk about uniqueness of solution?

Comment: @mezhang:  No, and he mentions the possibility of getting stuck in a loop.

Comment: @mezhang See my new answer (by brute force computation)